# Rails route Category find by name issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, find, categories, parameters

I want my users to be able to view /categories/comedy/ and see all posts available in the comedy category. Problem is that in my database all categories are with a capital, so comedy is Comedy. This means /categories/Comedy/ does work and /categories/comedy/ doesn't. I know it doesn't seem like a big deal but in the perspective of being as user-friendly as possible it is.

```
def show
    if @category = Category.find_by_name.(params[:id])
        @stories = @category.stories
    else
        redirect_to categories_path
        flash[:error] = "There is no such category"
    end
end
```

This is the code in my controller. I think I might have to uppercase the first letter at all time, but since I'm a newbie to Rails I have absolutely no idea how to accomplish this.

Thank you for reading this and hopefully thanks for your help!
Mats

Comment: your comedy capitatized because its name of model. Please post your routes.rb so we could help you with your issue. Also in `Category.find_by_name.(params[:id])` remove dot before `params`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`titleize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) if all words in the category name have their first letter capitalized:

```
Category.find_by_name(params[:id].titleize)
```

Otherwise, use [`humanize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize):

```
Category.find_by_name(params[:id].humanize)
```

Which one you choose will only matter for multi-word category names - `titleize` will make the first letter of all words uppercase, `humanize` will make the first letter of the first word uppercase.

`humanize` also has the side-effect of removing trailing `_id` from the string - which probably won't be an issue in your case.

I should also mention that database comparisons are often case-insensitive, so for non parameterized strings, this may not be necessary.  It becomes more necessary when you `parameterize` the route path, in which case multiple words become hyphen delimited.

Comment: Wauw that simple. I almost feel guilty asking! Titleize did the trick. Thanks for the quick response!